# Play MMS video stream iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, video-streaming, mms

There is a way  to play a MMS video stream? How can I achieve this?

I've found a way to stream a video that conforms the HTTP and RTSP protocol, but for the MMS I don't found anything.

Answer (score 0):

i suggest you should try Vitamio SDK. I used it for some projects and it worked perfectly.

[Vitamio Website](https://www.vitamio.org/en/docs/FAQ/2013/0509/12.htm)

[Download](https://github.com/yixia/Vitamio-iOS/releases)